# GParted hangs while resizing partition

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

I decided to shrink a FAT partition on my memory card by 768 MB to make place for a new one. GParted hangs on the fsck step. The progress bar halts and any window above it leaves the part of the window gray. A lot of such messages are in the output:

```
(gpartedbin:3076): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1414 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Is there any way to fix it? I'm using Linux Mint 17

Comment: did you try to do badblocks on the device?

Comment: `fsck.fat -tvV` found nothing